# How to exclude math environments from string replacement?

Tags: xparse, strings, xstring

I would like to have a command which applies another command to each line of the input. My approach is the following simple string replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring,xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\applySomeFormatting}{o}
{
    This line (#1) has been formatted successfully.
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\applySomeFormattingToEachLine}{m}
{
    \noexpandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\applySomeFormatting[#1]}{\\}{]\\\applySomeFormatting[}
}

\begin{document}
    \applySomeFormattingToEachLine{First line\\Second line\\Third line}
\end{document}
```

This basically works except for the case that there is a multi-line math environment in one of the lines, as the command shall not by applied to lines inside math environments.
Does anyone have an idea how those math environments can be excluded from the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a pair of `{}` around you math, which would protect the `\\` from beeing replaced by the string substitution.

I am however, not really sure if this is really what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring,xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\applySomeFormatting}{o}
{
    This line (#1) has been formatted successfully.
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\applySomeFormattingToEachLine}{m}
{
    \noexpandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\applySomeFormatting[#1]}{\\}{]\\\applySomeFormatting[}
}

\begin{document}
    \applySomeFormattingToEachLine{First line\\Second line\\Third line}

\bigskip    

My attempt:
    \applySomeFormattingToEachLine{Introduce some math:%
     {\begin{align}
    1+2=3\\
    3+4=7
\end{align}}\\ pure text }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this will do the job at least for every new document I am going to write. In case of importing already existing code, it would be nice if `\applySomeFormattingToEachLine` could add those brackets automatically in such a way that `\StrSubstitute` can "see" them. Do you have any idea how this could be done?

Comment: @emilG I have a few ideas, but no great one, and they all depend on what it is you really are trying to do. A little more info would help. Why do you use `\\`within text? Can't you just use an empty line in between? Could you use a different character? Why do you need math within all this? Basically, it would be desirable to show a better example.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I have realized that for my application adding the brackets automatically is actually not necessary. If you still want to know the background, I can tell you, but it is quite a long story which is why I did not include it into my question. By the way, now that you say it, I see that without knowing the background my requirements indeed sound quite weird ;).

Comment: @emilg could be that the community could give you a much better solution.